# Why my vim always chose another buffer

Tags: vim

I got a annoying situation:

Under /path1/to, I vim a file name "file1", but it looks I was always editing another file1 under different directory like /path2/to/file1 even if I type vim ./file under "/path1/to".

I type :buffers and got:

```
 1 # =  "/path1/to/file1"          line 1
 2 %a + "path2/to/file1"         line 426

/*please note buffer 2 is without / prefix while 1 dose */
```

Even I vim the file using "vim ./file1" under /path1/to/, the buffer is always pointing to buffer 2.

What kind of operation made this happen, why there are two buffers?
How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: They are not the same file though share the same name. If I use vi, instead of vim, the file I am editing is exactly the file that is expected to be editing.

Comment: Can you verify this behavior without plugins enabled: `vim --noplugin` or other modification in vimrc: `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: @MBO, with your suggestion, this annoying situation disappeared. I am checking the plugin and vimrc to see what caused this problem. Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To narrow the problem down. You can start vim without loading `vimrc` and `plugin`:

```
vim -u NONE /path1/to/file1 path2/to/file1
```

And print verbose message before switching buffers:

```
:20verbose bn
```

Comment: Typing "ls -al", check the output, and didn't find any hard/symbolic link between them.

Comment: With "vim -u NONE /path1/to/file1 path2/to/file1", I can get the right buffer now. I am checking any clue in .vim/plugin and .vimrc. One more question why ":20verbose bn" caused nothing to happen. Thanks!

Comment: @Joe.Z. You can use `vim -u NORC` to narrow the problem further. It'll skip `vimrc` and load `plugin`.

Comment: use "vim -u NORC file ", the problem is still there. use "vim --noplugin", it is not. I remove one plugin. It works normal now. Thank you very much.